# How to fix 1 warning generated while generating apk from kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[image]

try to convert kivy to apk with google.colab.

https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af

have repeating problem with last step.
!buildozer -v android debug

My os : windows 10